# Using a Jade mixin block as an attribute

Tags: pug

Whilst developing a library of Jade templates it has become desirable to use a mixin's block to serve as an attribute value, simplifying the syntax for the end user.

The end user will have a choice of 3 ways to create buttons; via a tags, button tags and input tags. For the input tags I would like to use the block as the value attribute so the syntax is always:

```
+abtn
    | A Button
+btn
    | Button
+ibtn
    | I Button
+abtn(disabled)
    | A Button Disabled
+btn(disabled)
    | Button Disabled
+ibtn(disabled)
    | I Button Disabled
```

At present a slimmed down version of the mixins looks like:

```
mixin abtn
    - attributes.href = attributes.href || '#'
    - attributes.role = attributes.role || 'button'
    - if (attributes.disabled) {
    -     attributes.class = (attributes.class === undefined) ? 'disabled' : attributes.class + ' disabled';
    -     attributes.disabled = null
    - }
    a.btn(attributes)
        block

mixin btn
    - attributes.type = attributes.type || 'button'
    button.btn(attributes)
        block

mixin ibtn
    - attributes.class = (attributes.class === undefined) ? 'btn' : attributes.class + ' btn';
    - attributes.type = attributes.type || 'button'
    input(attributes=attributes)
```

The trouble is specifying the value attribute for ibtn requires the end user syntax to be:

```
+abtn
    | A Button
+btn
    | Button
+ibtn(value='I Button')
+abtn(disabled)
    | A Button Disabled
+btn(disabled)
    | Button Disabled
+ibtn(value='I Button Disabled', disabled)
```

Which is inconsistent.

Is it possible to access block via the inbuilt javascript, so that a non-whitespace version of its contents can be used in an attribute? If so how?

**EDIT**

To clarify, I would like the following jade code:

```
+ibtn
      | My button value
```

to output:

```
<input value="My button value">
```

Comment: Can you define "a non-whitespace version of its contents" using an example? It appears [you're using this](http://jade-lang.com/reference/), is that right? Are you using any other resources / information for your development?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott added a usage example which explain just what I am after. Regarding any other resources/information there are lots of unrelated ones, but most of this is trial, error and the official documentation.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use an `<input>` instead of a `<button>`? Blocks will only work with non-self-closing tags.

Comment: @Craig yes because there is a semantic difference for SEO. FYI these are for a Bootstrap helper library.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a syntax problem. When you run a `mixin`, becomes in this way, since the parentheses you can give arguments. That is so:

```
mixin myMixin (arg1, arg2)
   p=arg1
   p=arg2
+myMixin('Jade is Cool', 'Yeahh!')
```

is rendered into...

```
<p>Jade is Cool</p>
<p>Yeahh!</p>
```

In this case you want to spend `attributes`, it becomes as follows:

```
mixin myMixin (arg1, arg2)
    p( id=attributes.id )=arg1
    p( class=attributes.class, value=attributes.value )=arg2
+myMixin('Jade is Cool', 'Yeahh!').myClass#MyId( value="Kool" )
```

which is rendered as ...

```
<p id="MyId">Jade is Cool</p>
<p class="myClass" value="Kool">Yeahh!</p>
```

Note standing twice parentheses, the first makes the `mixin` leading arguments and run second are attributes `mixin`. Where applicable:

```
+abtn()
    | A Button
+btn()
    | Button
+ibtn()(value='I Button')
+abtn()(disabled)
    | A Button Disabled
+btn()(disabled)
    | Button Disabled
+ibtn()(value='I Button Disabled', disabled)
```

Remember that `mixin`s are functions in javascript.